# How can I use regex to exclude lines with extra characters?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a bunch of email addresses:

abc@google.com

bdc@yahoo.com

**\\ske@google.com**

I'd like to delete the bolded line because there is extra character in the string other than @ . and letters. How do I do this ?

Comment: A better way to think of this is that you only want lines that match a certain pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through awk,

```
$ awk '/^\w+@\w+/{print}' file
abc@google.com
bdc@yahoo.com
```

Awk searches for the lines which starts with one or more word character followed by an `@` symbol and again followed by one or more word characters. If it founds any, then prints the whole line.

This line `\\ske@google.com` wouldn't starts with a word character, so it not get printed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak -n '/^[[:alnum:]]*@/p' file
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `vim` to take care of it too:

```
vim -c 'v/^[[:alnum:]]*@/d' -c 'wq' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a perl module:

```
perl -ne 'use Email::Valid; print if Email::Valid->address($_)'
```